# The simplex algorithm--example

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

[Here](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ffischer/teaching/opt/notes/notes8.pdf) on the page 30, why $(z_3,z_3)=1$: as written on that page 30:

> minimize the sum of the artificial variables, starting from the BFS where the absolute value of the artificial variable for each constraint, or of the slack variable in case there is no artificial variable, is equal to that of the right handside.

But the r.h.s. of it is $2$ and not $1$. What does it precisely mean that highlighted text above?

Comment: Choose a better book!

Comment: Choose a better study subject! The simplex method and LP in general is a very algorithmic-ish area of maths in which concepts are more than often given without motivation. I remember taking a class in it and nobody really knew what was going on

Comment: @NoChance  But my simple question should have a simple answer, right?

Comment: @user122424, of course, your question is valid. It has been about 30 years since I did this, I wish I could help. There must be great books by now that explain this stuff in a more clear way.

Comment: @NoChance You *don't* need to ping OP by `@user122424` since the post owner will be notified in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain what's happening before getting back to the text.  In the standard form,

\begin{align}
\max z= \quad& -6 x_1 - 3 x_2 \tag{$\star$}\label{z1} \\
\text{s.t.} \quad& x_1+x_2-z_1 = 1 \tag{1}\label{c1} \\
& 2x_1-x_2-z_2 = 1 \tag{2}\label{c2} \\
& 3x_2+z_3 = 2 \tag{3}\label{c3} \\
& x_1, x_2, z_1, z_2, z_3 \geq 0. \tag{FC}\label{fc}
\end{align}

To find an "obvious BFS" (p.29), we include $z_3$ as a basic variable, but *not* $z_1,z_2$ since we *can't* have $z_1 = z_2 = -1$ due to \eqref{fc}.

To start the [two-phase-simplex](/questions/tagged/two-phase-simplex), we need a BFS, so we add artificial variables $y_1$ and $y_2$ to LHS of \eqref{c1} and \eqref{c2} respectively, so that we get an "obvious BFS" $(y_1,y_2,z_3) = (1,1,2)$.

\begin{align}
\min w= \quad& y_1 + y_2 \tag{#}\label{w1} \\
\text{s.t.} \quad& x_1+x_2-z_1+y_1 = 1 \tag{1'}\label{c12} \\
& 2x_1-x_2-z_2+y_2 = 1 \tag{2'}\label{c22} \\
& 3x_2+z_3 = 2 \tag{3}\label{c32} \\
& x_1, x_2, z_1, z_2, z_3, y_1, y_2 \geq 0. \tag{FC'}\label{fc2}
\end{align}

This allows us to write a simplex tableau, in which the basic variables are $y_1$, $y_2$ and $z_3$.  This explains why in the simplex tableau, the $z_3$-row $z_3$-column is $1$.  The RHS of the intial simplex tableau echoes the "obvious BFS", so the RHS of $z_3$-row is $2$.

Now, let's decode the quoted text.

- minimize the sum of the artificial variables ($\min y_1 + y_2$)
- starting from the BFS ($(y_1,y_2,z_3)$)

  - the absolute value of the artificial variable for each constraint ($|y_1|,|y_2|$ in \eqref{c12} & \eqref{c22} respectively), OR
  - of the slack variable in case there is no artificial variable (\eqref3 has *no* artificial variable, $z_3$ is a slack variable)
- is equal to that of the right handside ($=(1,1,2)$)